# Show min and max values of array that will come from user input

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, do-while, turbo-c++

I am making a simple program that will ask for an input, put it inside an array (number[i]) and convert it to three different units. After converting it to different units I must be able to show the lowest and highest number that the user has given.

I am using a do while loop to get input from user, and after the `do while loop` i have put a `for loop` that will calculate the min and max number from the input that is inside the number[i] array. But after putting in 2 inputs, the program only showed me the highest number, the lowest number shows me `0`.

Here's what it looks like.

```
do{
clrscr();
cout<<"Enter a number:";
cin>>number[i];
cout<<"\nPlease choose a unit";
cout<<"\n<A> meter";
cout<<"\n<B> centimeter";
cout<<"\n<C> inch";
cout<<"\n<D> feet";
cout<<"\nPlease enter your chosen unit: ";
cin>>unit;
switch(unit)
{
case 'a':
case 'A':
 i=0;
 m = number[i] * 1;
 cm = 1000 * m;
 in =  m / 0.0254;
 ft =  m/0.3048;
 cout<<"\nYou have chosen meter for unit";
 cout<<"\nYou have entered "<<number[i]<<" meters";
 cout<<"\n"<<m<<" meters is equal to\n"<<cm<<" centimeters";
 cout<<"\n"<<in<<" inches";
 cout<<"\n"<<ft<<" feet";
 cout<<"\n\nDo you want to input another value? y/n:";
 cin>>y;
 if(y=='y')
 {
 x=1;
 }
 else if(y=='n')

 {
 x=0;
 }
 break;

case 'b':
case 'B':
 cm = number[i] * 1;
 m = cm /1000;
 in = cm * 0.393701;
 ft = cm * 0.0328084;
 cout<<"\nYou have chosen centimeter for unit";
 cout<<"\nYou have entered "<<number[i]<<" centimeters";
 cout<<"\n"<<cm<<" centimeters is equal to\n"<<m<<" meters";
 cout<<"\n"<<in<<" inches";
 cout<<"\n"<<ft<<" feet";
 cout<<"\n\nDo you want to input another value? y/n:";
 cin>>y;
 if(y=='y')
 {
 x=1;
 }
 else if(y=='n')
 {
 x=0;
 break;
 }
break;
case 'c':
case 'C':
 in = number[i] * 1;
 m = in * 0.0254;
 cm = in * 2.54;
 ft = in * 0.0833333;
 cout<<"\nYou have chosen inches for unit";
 cout<<"\nYou have entered "<<number[i]<<" inches";
 cout<<"\n"<<in<<" inches is equal to\n"<<m<<" meters";
 cout<<"\n"<<cm<<" centimeters";
 cout<<"\n"<<ft<<" feet";
 cout<<"\n\nDo you want to input another value? y/n:";
 cin>>y;
 if(y=='y')
 {
 x=1;
 }
 else if(y=='n')
 {
 x=0;
 }

break;
case 'd':
case 'D':
 ft = number[i] * 1;
 m = ft*0.3048;
 in = ft*12;
 cm = ft * 30.48;
 cout<<"\nYou have chosen feet for unit";
 cout<<"\nYou have entered "<<number[i]<<" feet";
 cout<<"\n"<<ft<<" feet is equal to\n"<<m<<" meters";
 cout<<"\n"<<cm<<" centimeters";
 cout<<"\n"<<in<<" inches";
 cout<<"\n\nDo you want to input another value? y/n:";
 cin>>y;
 if(y=='y')
 {
 x=1;
 }
 else if(y=='n')
 {
 x=0;
 }
break;
default:
cout<<"\nYou have entered an invalid choice!";
x=1;
break;

}

}while(x==1);

for(i=0; i<sizeof(number)/sizeof(*number);i++)
{
if(mn>number[i])
{
    mn=number[i];
}
else if (mx<number[i])
    mx= number[i];
}

cout<<"\nHighest number is : "<<mx;
cout<<"\nLowest number is: "<<mn;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130032/discussion-on-question-by-james-bong-show-min-and-max-values-of-array-that-will).

Answer (score 1):

if you are getting the highest number for lowest number output there is a mistake in your second `cout` statement you continue to have the output for `mx`

Currently you are using `mx` for lowest number

```
cout<<"\nLowest number is: "<<mx;
```

Fixed

```
cout<<"\nLowest number is: "<<mn;
```

Comment: i have run the program and entered 2 different values, my first input is 10 and after pressing y to input again i have entered 20. if my program is correct the lowest number should be 10 and the highest number should be 20, but the lowest number i am getting is 0.

Comment: Plz note the question has been edited, this answer was written for previous version of the question before downvoting.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`minmax`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax):

```
const auto result = minmax(cbegin(number), cend(number));

cout << "\nHighest number is : " << result.first << "\nLowest number is: " result.second << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing `i` with `number[i]`, instead compare it with the size of `number`.